# Save AWS Polly mp3 file to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-polly

I am trying to send some text to AWS Polly to convert to speech and then save that mp3 file to S3. That part seems to work now.

```
// Send text to AWS Polly
$client_polly = new Aws\Polly\PollyClient([
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $aws_useKey,
        'secret' => $aws_secret,
    ]
]);

$text = 'Test. Test. This is a sample text to be synthesized.';
$voice = 'Matthew';

 $result_polly = $client_polly->startSpeechSynthesisTask([
    'Text' => $text,
    'TextType' => 'text',
    'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
    'OutputS3BucketName' => $aws_bucket,
    'OutputS3KeyPrefix' => 'files/audio/,
    'VoiceId' => $voice,
    'ACL' => 'public-read'
]);


echo $result_polly['ObjectURL'];
```

I'm also trying to accomplish couple other things:

1. Make mp3 file publicly accessible. Currently I have to go to AWS console to
   click "Make Public" button. It seems that 'ACL' => 'public-read' doesn't work for me
2. I need to return full URL of the mp3 file. For some reason $result_polly['ObjectURL']; doesn't get any value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ACL` field in the [`StartSpeechSynthesisTask` call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-polly-2016-06-10.html#startspeechsynthesistask):

```
$result = $client->startSpeechSynthesisTask([
    'LanguageCode' => 'arb|cmn-CN|cy-GB|da-DK|de-DE|en-AU|en-GB|en-GB-WLS|en-IN|en-US|es-ES|es-MX|es-US|fr-CA|fr-FR|is-IS|it-IT|ja-JP|hi-IN|ko-KR|nb-NO|nl-NL|pl-PL|pt-BR|pt-PT|ro-RO|ru-RU|sv-SE|tr-TR',
    'LexiconNames' => ['<string>', ...],
    'OutputFormat' => 'json|mp3|ogg_vorbis|pcm', // REQUIRED
    'OutputS3BucketName' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'OutputS3KeyPrefix' => '<string>',
    'SampleRate' => '<string>',
    'SnsTopicArn' => '<string>',
    'SpeechMarkTypes' => ['<string>', ...],
    'Text' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'TextType' => 'ssml|text',
    'VoiceId' => 'Aditi|Amy|Astrid|Bianca|Brian|Carla|Carmen|Celine|Chantal|Conchita|Cristiano|Dora|Emma|Enrique|Ewa|Filiz|Geraint|Giorgio|Gwyneth|Hans|Ines|Ivy|Jacek|Jan|Joanna|Joey|Justin|Karl|Kendra|Kimberly|Lea|Liv|Lotte|Lucia|Mads|Maja|Marlene|Mathieu|Matthew|Maxim|Mia|Miguel|Mizuki|Naja|Nicole|Penelope|Raveena|Ricardo|Ruben|Russell|Salli|Seoyeon|Takumi|Tatyana|Vicki|Vitoria|Zeina|Zhiyu', // REQUIRED
]);
```

Therefore, you will either need to make another call to Amazon S3 to change the ACL of the object, or use an Amazon S3 **Bucket Policy** to make the bucket (or a path within the bucket) public.

The output location is given in the `OutputUri` field (*NOT* `OutputUrl` -- URI vs URL).